# Using Or in Php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use or logical operator in Php to display a message if either of the argument is true, but am always getting the wrong output here is my code. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$username = test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username'])); 

$emailregex = preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $username); //ValidatingEmail

$usernameregex = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/",$username);  //checking if name   contains only letters and white spaces;

if ( !$emailregex   || !$usernameregex ) { //if it didn't match either
    echo "InvalidUserName";
    exit();
} else if ( $emailregex  || $usernameregex ) { //in case either matched
    $myusername =$username;
    echo("Hello".$myusername);
}?>
```

Problem is even if I enter a valid name or email am getting `"invalidusername"`
Is my logic wrong?

Comment: first condition should use &&

Comment: "Not a or not b" is not *"didn't match either"*. It's "didn't match at least one of them".

Comment: I want user to be able to log in using either email or username

Comment: Also, if you want something to happen for the opposite case, you don't need a reversed `if` again. You just need an `if (condition) ... else ...`.

Comment: *"Is my logic wrong?"* -- yes. The comment says *"if it didn't match either"* but the code checks if it didn't match any. It should be `if (! $emailregex && ! $usernameregex)` or `if (! ($emailregex || $usernameregex))` (they the same). After this fix, the `if` statement on the `else` branch becomes superfluous; its condition will always match.

Comment: Yeah thanks i get you

Comment:   logic error

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php

$username = test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username'])); 

$emailregex = preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $username); //ValidatingEmail

$usernameregex = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/",$username);  //checking if name   contains only letters and white spaces;


if (!$emailregex && !$usernameregex ) { 
echo "Username must be valid name or email";
exit();
}
else {
$myusername =$username;
echo("Hello".$myusername);
}
?>
```